# Set OSCAR_MISSING_IMAGE_URL with django-storages S3 Boto

Tags: django, boto, django-oscar

How do I set the `django-oscar` setting `OSCAR_MISSING_IMAGE_URL` when using S3BotoStorage as my backend? I am also using django compressor.

I have created a `media` folder in my S3 bucket, and manually uploaded the image to the bucket subdirectory. My current setting is

```
OSCAR_MISSING_IMAGE_URL = MEDIA_URL + "/media/image_not_found.svg"
```

Where `MEDIA_URL` is my S3 bucket URL.

Any way to get it to render the missing image correctly?

Answer (score 3):

While not familiar with the specifics of `django-oscar`, [according to the docs](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/settings.html#oscar-missing-image-url), `OSCAR_MISSING_IMAGE_URL` by default, is set to `image_not_found.jpg`.

So I guess in your case you only need `image_not_found.svg`. There is no need to pass the `MEDIA_URL`. Also, according to the [inline docs in the code](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/abstract_models.py#L1135-L1158), sorl (the thumbnailing engine) requires all files to be inside `MEDIA_ROOT`.